# Asignacion de nil a un struct con un metodo en Go

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, go

¿Es correcto utilizar esto para hacer nil a la instancia de un struct ?

este código es de un nodo de una lista doblemente enlazada

```golang
func (n *Node) Kill()  {
    n.next = nil
    n.prev = nil
    n = nil // Mi pregunta esta relacionada con si es necesaria y funciona esta parte del código
}
```

esta parte es usada dentro del código de la lista para eliminar un nodo

```golang
node.Prev().SetNext(next)
node.Next().SetPrev(prev)
node.Kill()
```

Mi duda surge debido al código que se encuentra en "containers/list" de la librería estándar, en especial las partes que dicen `//avoid memory leaks`, el código es el siguiente

```
// remove removes e from its list, decrements l.len
func (l *List) remove(e *Element) {
    e.prev.next = e.next
    e.next.prev = e.prev
    e.next = nil // avoid memory leaks
    e.prev = nil // avoid memory leaks
    e.list = nil
    l.len--
}
```

Comment: tecnicamente es correcto, porque le estas indicando al GC que la direccion de memoria donde estaba esa variable puede limpiarse